# Does ingesting nitric oxide capsules help treating a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons

Ingesting nitric oxide capsules supposedly increases blood flow. For example, this [Nitric Oxide Supplement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CCHBA8U)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170429235507/https://www.amazon.com/SHEER-N-O-Nitric-Oxide-Supplement/dp/B00CCHBA8U/ref=zg_bs_6973697011_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=K9DVB76KDVWBEA52ANBS)) claims:

[image]

Does ingesting nitric oxide capsules help treating a tendinopathy? (since increasing the blood flow around the tendons may help heal)

I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)

Related:

- [What are the long-term side effects of glyceryl trinitrate patches used to treat a tendinopathy?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/5752/43)

Comment: The research apparently is [very conflicting on the blood flow idea with tendinopathy](http://stevenlow.org/overcoming-tendonitis) but [Nitric Oxide does actually seem to help to increase blood flow through vasodilation](https://doi.org/10.1113/jphysiol.2002.021477)

Comment: @Chris NO is a gas; as a signalling molecule it is one thing – given the link, I stopped reading at "Important information. Ingredients: Gelatin (capsule), Magnesium Stearate and Silicon Dioxide."  at Franck: Whether it's about NO or this specific pill: please try to reproduce the concrete ingredients, if I am mistaken- but they surely pack not just the gas and the ingredients I read from your link do not provide any of that. Updates to this question are vital.

Comment: Personally, I stop reading when I see words like "It's like a firehouse of muscle-feed." That right there tells me the whole thing is a load of marketing crap.

Comment: @CareyGregory "marketing crap" sometimes promotes evidence-based treatments.

Comment: Really? I kind of doubt that. If there's real value to something it's unlikely that advertising people will be the first to know about it.